# Which rotation groups of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are symmetry groups of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: lie-groups, rotations, symmetric-groups, isometry

Definition. Let $G < SO(n)$ be the rotation group of some compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ We call $G$ chiral if there exists a compact set $K$ such that its symmetry group equals $G$.

**Question:** classification of chiral subgroups of $SO(n)$.

Statement. For $n \leq 3$ chiral $\Leftrightarrow$ discrete.

Proof. (non-trivial for n = 3) $\Leftarrow$ Any discrete subgroup is a symmetry group of some compact (place a small compact with no symmetries far from 0 and act on it with your group).
$\Rightarrow$ If a subgroup is not discrete, then it necessarily contains all rotations around some line. Then the compact set with each point contains a circle around this line. Then the compact has all mirror symmetries with respect to the planes passing through this line

P.S. I used to think that this is true in all dimensions and put this hypothesis in the title of the question. Later I realized (which was also pointed out to me in the comments) that there are non-discrete chiral subgroups for $n = 4$, after which I edited my question. I think I understood a lot about the classification of chiral subgroups among one-dimensional ones, but I still need to check some things.

Comment: The symmetry through a line   do not reverse orientation : his matrix is  diag $(-1,-1,1)$ in a convenient base.

Comment: @Thomas Corrected a typo, thanks

Comment: This fails in 4D, for instance, nontrivial torus knots are orbits of 1-parameter rotation groups but do not admit orientation reversing symmetries (they are even chiral).

Comment: Yes, I realized the same thing a few hours ago! Apparently, I proved that this is true in all $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $[n/2]$ is odd (the integer part of division by 2). If $[n/2]$ is even, then among the one-dimensional subgroups, only the symmetry groups of nontrivial rational windings of tori are subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$. Are there exceptions among subgroups of higher dimensions?

Comment: You should update your question to reflect what you know and what you do not. Also, $[x]$ is an unclear notation, consider using the [floor and the ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: Yes, I will do it right now, I didn't have time before.

Comment: I was wrong when I wrote my comment about floor(n/2)